# Internet Explorer download using Visual Basic

Tags: vba, internet-explorer-11

I have a script that opens a URL in Internet Explorer, enters the username and password and clicks Submit. I can't get past the default Internet Explorer open/save prompt. Is this possible?

```
Call Main

Function Main
    Set IE = WScript.CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application", "IE_")
    IE.Visible = True
    IE.Navigate "https://www.blahblahblah.com"
    Wait IE
    With IE.Document
        .getElementByID("ctrluser").value = "blahblahblah"
        .getElementByID("ctrlpass").value = "blahblahblah"        
        .getElementByID("frmSubmit").Click
    End With
End Function

Sub Wait(IE)
  Do
    WScript.Sleep 500
  Loop While IE.ReadyState < 4 And IE.Busy
End Sub
```

Also, can you change the default download location to a specific network folder?

Comment: Is URLMON an option here? Does the website provided a download link after clicking that you can use? You can then specify the download path. Otherwise, easy to add an extra script line to move the file of interest to another folder.

Comment: Handling the open/save prompt is a common question on SO... Did none of those methods work? Which did you try?